# Restler 3: 404 on all routes

Tags: php, restler

I am trying to use Restler in a PHP app api, but I am getting a `404` object returned on all requests.  I have reviewed the following similar questions:

- [Restler Returns Always Not Found With Or Without Index.php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498792/restler-returns-always-not-found-with-or-without-index-php/12512802)
- [Restler always returns 404: Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20488815/restler-always-returns-404-not-found)
- [Restler API framework installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12074979/restler-api-framework-installation)

I am almost certain that the problem lies in the server configuration.  I can run the example files in my local environment, but as soon as I push it to the live server, this problem persists.

For example, when I copy the folder `_001_helloworld`, which works locally,  [to my server](http://dev.myaxiom.ca/api/_001_helloworld/), I get `404` response body:

```
{
error: {
code: 404,
message: "Not Found"
},
debug: {
source: "Routes.php:431 at route stage",
stages: {
success: [
"get"
],
failure: [
"route",
"negotiate",
"message"
]
}
}
}
```

[Here is my PHPInfo](http://dev.myaxiom.ca/api/phpinfo.php)

How can I fix all routes returning 404 in the response body in Restler.

Answer (score 1):

Ik spent an entire day solving this exact same problem but finally managed to do so. On localhost everything was running smoothly but on the server I got the same 404 error ("Routes.php:431 at route stage") as you did.

This is what solved it for me:

I had to move the .htaccess to the root of the website and then changed the RewriteRule to have [location of your api]/index.php instead of just index.php.

My .htaccess file:

```
Options -MultiViews
DirectoryIndex api/helloworld/index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^$ api/helloworld/index.php [QSA,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api/helloworld/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
    php_flag display_errors Off
</IfModule>
```

Basic hello world example can now be called like this:  GET [servername]/say/hello